# Fill out content of div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this form on page some.php and i want when i click on submit button to make query for this data from form and display it in index.php in `<div id="content">` . I try to do something with jquery but im not good in that, so if someone can help me? :)
EDIT: i tryed something like this but its not working in index.php.Is it possible to send form data to blah.php and on blah.php execute query and then loaded it in index.php in `<div id="content">` ?

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
$my_html  = "<script type='text/javascript'>"  ;
$my_html .= "$('#content').fadeIn(1500);" ;
$my_html .= " $('#content').load('blah.php');";

$my_html .= "</script>";
echo $my_html ;
}
?>
```

some.php

```
<form id="search" name="search" method="post" action="index.php">
     Price from:
    <input type="text" name="from" id="from" width="50px" />
     Price to: 
     <input type="text" name="to" id="to" width="50px" />
<input type="submit" class="btn_advancedsearch" name="search" id="search" value="Search" />
     </form>
```

Comment: And what 'something' do you want to do 'with jQuery'?

Comment: in index.php <div id="content"> i already have some data so when i click submit on page some.php i want to change content of div in index.php

Comment: Javascript runs client side.  It does not need to be echo'd via PHP, and should not be returned by PHP, but should be on the page to start.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
   loadContent()
   {
           $('#content').load('blah.php')
   }
</script>
<form id="search" name="search" method="post" action="index.php">
     Price from:
    <input type="text" name="from" id="from" width="50px" />
     Price to: 
     <input type="text" name="to" id="to" width="50px" />
<input type="button" onclick="loadContent()" class="btn_advancedsearch" name="search" id="search" value="Search" />
     </form>
```

Obviously you would have to make sure blah.php returns whatever content you want in your div - you could put firstname and lastname in querystring.

Comment: can u explain it a littlebit more?

Comment: Perhaps, but that would also require you to explain your question a bit more. The answer cannot usually be more specific than the question is. I suggest you think about what the very core of your question is and then ask exactly that instead.

Comment: I have search.php page and there i have form with textboxes.I want to enter in that textboxes firstname and lastname and when i click on submit button i want to display firstname and lastname from database  in index.php in <div id="content">.I already have some content in that div so i want to replace that content with result from query.Is it better now?

Comment: i tryed this but its nothing happening hmm

Comment: You have to break it down to exactly WHAT is not working. You are taking on a too big problem at once, I think. Start with figuring out how you get content in the div from another page. If you do not know why it's not working, start with using Google Chrome Developer Tools (F12) or FireBug for FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to this?

```
if ($_POST['from'])
{
// form is sent
}
```

Comment: i need to change content of div where i already have some data